# Loop Through jQuery Elements Separately and Animate on Page Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've managed to get a simple stat counter running up from zero to a given value where it's only activated on page scroll, but it's not exactly as I was aiming for.

The problem is, all of the ".counter" elements are firing off at the same time as soon as the first element comes into view, as opposed to waiting until each individual element is actually visible on screen. So as soon at the window hits the containing div, all of them go off at once.

I'd like to have each individual .counter wait until it's fully visible before it fires off.

Here's what I've got so far:

HTML:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="stats">
  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="400"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="350"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="12"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="97"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="899"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="4"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="0"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="6"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery...

```
    (function($) {

  $(function() {

    var $counters = $('.counter'); //contains all elements of counter class

    var $window = $(window);

    $window.on('scroll', function(e) {
      $counters.each(function(i, elem) { //loop through each element
        if ($(this).hasClass('counted')) // check if already animated
          return;
        animateCounter($(this));
      });
    });
  });

  function animateCounter(elem) {
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // calculate distance from top of window
    var winBottom = winTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top; // element distance from top of page
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    if ((elemBottom <= winBottom) && (elemTop >= winTop)) {
      $('.counter').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        jQuery({
          Counter: 0
        }).animate({
          Counter: $this.attr('count')
        }, {
          duration: 3000,
          step: function() {
            $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
          }
        });
        $this.removeClass('counter').addClass('counted');
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ahfL4jxr/11/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Issue is (I think) `$(this)` are all of the `.counter` elements and since it's a class selector, it will run for all. I'll dabble a bit and see if I can fix it.

Comment: literally one change :). Fixed in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you were so close.

You're targeting all of the elements instead of the one in the argument you pushed through.

In your `animateCounter()` function, `$('.counter')` should change to `$(elem)`

https://jsfiddle.net/7xsv33hf/

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code was that you were correctly checking the scrolling distance, but applying the animation to all of your counters.

```js
 (function($) {
  
   $(function() {
    
     var $counters = $('.counter'); //contains all elements of counter class
      
     var $window = $(window);
      
     $window.on('scroll', function(e) {
       $counters.each(function(i, elem) { //loop through each element
         if ($(this).hasClass('counted')) // check if already animated
           return;
         animateCounter($(this));
       });
     });
   });
    
   function animateCounter(elem) {
     var winTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // calculate distance from top of window
     var winBottom = winTop + $(window).height();
     var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top; // element distance from top of page
     var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
      
     if ((elemBottom <= winBottom) && (elemTop >= winTop)) {
         var $this = elem;
         jQuery({
           Counter: 0
         }).animate({
           Counter: $this.attr('count')
         }, {
           duration: 3000,
           step: function() {
             $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
           }
         });
         $this.removeClass('counter').addClass('counted');
       
     }
   }
 })(jQuery);
```

```css
#stats {
  font-size: 0;
}

#stats * {
  color: #000;
}

.single-stat {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

.stat-container {
  position: relative;
}

.top-line {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}

.stat {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 0;
}

.bottom-line {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.animateBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.animateBlock {
  opacity: 0;
}

.left.animated {
  transform: translateX(-40px);
}

.right.animated {
  transform: translateX(40px);
}

.top.animated {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}

.bottom.animated {
  transform: translateY(40px);
}

.animated {
  animation: come-in 0.5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes come-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="stats">
  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="400"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="350"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="12"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="97"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="899"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="4"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="0"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="6"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cndbqeck/

Answer (score 0):

there was an error in your javascript in animateCounter() function, you did an unnecessary foreach because in the function you already passed the element you need to animate when you call it.

```js
(function($) {

  $(function() {

    var $counters = $('.counter'); //contains all elements of counter class

    var $window = $(window);

    $window.on('scroll', function(e) {
      $counters.each(function(i, elem) { //loop through each element
        if ($(this).hasClass('counted')) // check if already animated
          return;
        animateCounter($(this));
      });
    });
  });

  function animateCounter(elem) {
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // calculate distance from top of window
    var winBottom = winTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top; // element distance from top of page
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    if ((elemBottom <= winBottom) && (elemTop >= winTop)) {
      var $this = $(elem);
      jQuery({
        Counter: 0
      }).animate({
        Counter: $this.attr('count')
      }, {
        duration: 3000,
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
        }
      });
      $this.removeClass('counter').addClass('counted');
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#stats {
  font-size: 0;
}

#stats * {
  color: #000;
}

.single-stat {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

.stat-container {
  position: relative;
}

.top-line {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}

.stat {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 0;
}

.bottom-line {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.animateBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.animateBlock {
  opacity: 0;
}

.left.animated {
  transform: translateX(-40px);
}

.right.animated {
  transform: translateX(40px);
}

.top.animated {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}

.bottom.animated {
  transform: translateY(40px);
}

.animated {
  animation: come-in 0.5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes come-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="stats">
  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="400"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="350"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="12"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="97"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="899"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="4"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="0"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="single-stat">
    <h6 class="top-line">title</h6>
    <div class="stat-container">
      <h6 class="stat"><span class="counter" count="6"></span></h6>
    </div>
    <h6 class="bottom-line">bottom line</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```